# SQL optimizing large or query

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I'm attempting to run a query to find any matches between multiple phone number columns on two tables and it is taking far too long (>5 minutes) and this is with the data filtered as much as possible. I've separated the actual columns I can search from both tables into their own tables, just to reduce the amount of total rows.

**This is from a legacy application I inherited.**

**Query**

```
select count(b.bid) 
from customers_with_phone c,buyers_orders_with_phone b 
where 
   (b.hphone=c.pprim or b.hphone=c.phome or b.hphone=c.pwork or b.hphone=c.pother) 
or (b.wphone=c.pprim or b.wphone=c.phome or b.wphone=c.pwork or b.wphone=c.pother) 
or (b.cphone=c.pprim or b.cphone=c.phome or b.cphone=c.pwork or b.cphone=c.pother) 
group by b.bid;
```

**Tables**

```
mysql> show columns from customers_with_phone;
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| pnum   | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| pprim  | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| phome  | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| pwork  | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| pother | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+

mysql> show columns from buyers_orders_with_phone;
+--------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| bid    | text | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| hphone | text | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| wphone | text | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| cphone | text | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

**Explain**

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows  | filtered | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |  8673 |   100.00 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 75931 |   100.00 | Using where; Using join buffer               |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
```

I realize that neither tables have a primary key, as these are only the columns that I need to search on and I extracted these columns from their original table. But using the original table it takes even longer because there is far more data to filter through.

I have other queries that are similar to this that will work with much more data so if I can make this one work in a reasonable time, I can get the others to work similarly.

Comment: If they are all phone numbers, have you thought about splitting them out into their own table (customer,type,number) / (order,type,number) & indexing that?

Comment: The problem is I can't index them. The way the system was built sometimes the phone number was required, sometimes only the cellphone was required, sometimes no phone number at all is present.

Comment: why for good sakes would you store phone numbers in text fields...?

Comment: Don't ask. Legacy application that I have to deal with now. Older phone number records use dashes and periods in the number itself...

Answer (score 0):

A primary key is not a optimazation. What you need are non clustered index on your telephone text fields (one index per column). With these, you won't need to extract your data to seperate tables.

Comment: But be aware: An Index could need maintanence!

Comment: As I just posted above: "The problem is I can't index them. The way the system was built sometimes the phone number was required, sometimes only the cellphone was required, sometimes no phone number at all is present."

Comment: You have to understand your sql statement: your tables are **fully** scanned quite a few times and this needs a lot of time. To reduce this, you have to index your columns. Then only your index are partly scanned and not the table. That's the only way, big data could be handled.

Answer (score 0):

The legacy query is awful, sorry. It is full cartesian product.

The data structure cannot handle such queries effectively. You have 3 fields in one table and 4 in other and try to figure if any pair matches.

Possibly primary key and key for every phone column can improve this query, not sure, but it can make worse delete/insert/update performance.

Btw, you wrote that impossible to index by nullable column. It's not correct.

I can believe in only radical solution - change data structure or adding some kind of caching mechanism with trigger. But it is hard.